# jQuery On Click not working

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting my event handler to fire. I'm calling JSON into the page as below. I then want to be able to click one of the buttons I have created which will execute the 'hello there' alert. It works with every other element on the page, but not the `<button>`.

Can anyone help?

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('/api/v1/recipe/?format=json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.objects, function(i, recipe) {
      $('table#recipes').append('<tr><td>' + recipe.title + '</td><td>' + recipe.ingredients + '</td><td>' + recipe.method + '</td><td><button class="btn" type="button" id="rmv">remove</button></td></tr>');
      });
    });

    $('rmv').on('click', function() {
      alert('hello there!');
    });
  });
```

**recipe.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
      <form action='' method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="go baby!">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="recipes">
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Ingredients</th>
          <th>Method</th>
          <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% block recipes %}{% endblock recipes %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: ajax is asynchronous.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you have got the selector wrong it should be

```
$('#rmv')
```

and if you are appending the element dynamically you should use it like

```
$(document).on('click','#rmv',function(e) {
  //handler code here
});
```

your loop in the ajax success call back will probably produce elements with duplicate ids, which is wrong, so as @Alnitak mentioned you can switch to class selector like after modifying the cde

```
$.getJSON('/api/v1/recipe/?format=json', function(data) {
  $.each(data.objects, function(i, recipe) {
    $('table#recipes').append('<tr><td>' + recipe.title + '</td><td>' + recipe.ingredients + '</td><td>' + recipe.method + '</td><td><button class="btn rmv" type="button" >remove</button></td></tr>');
  });
});
```

and the selector will look like

```
$(document).on('click','.rmv',function(e) {
  //handler code here
});
```

Comment: Just an FYI, attaching event handlers directly to the element itself is generally more efficient than attaching everything to the document object.

Comment: would you perhaps care to upvote my answer, rather than copying bits based on the issues that I spotted and no-one else did? ;-)

Comment: @JIA yeah, but I'm _nearly_ at 100k :)

Comment: BTW, and per Brad's comment and my answer the (correct) middle ground here is to register the event handler on `$('#recipes')` which ensures that the click event bubbles no further than it has to.

Comment: THanks i was doing it the wrong way and asking myself why it wasnt working :)

Comment: You made my day with  `if you are appending the element dynamically`

Answer (score 6):

Try this. Move this code inside `callback`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('/api/v1/recipe/?format=json', function(data) {
            $.each(data.objects, function(i, recipe) {
                $('table#recipes').append('<tr><td>' + recipe.title + '</td><td>' + recipe.ingredients + '</td><td>' + recipe.method + '</td><td><button class="btn" type="button" id="rmv">remove</button></td></tr>');
            });

        $('#rmv').on('click', function() {
            alert('hello there!');
        });
        });


    });
```

OR use jQuery.on

```
$(document).on("click", "#rmv",function() {
                alert('hello there!');
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Document ready was exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure there's not more than one element with ID `rmv`.  ID's have to be unique, but you appear to be adding multiple recipes, each with their own "remove" button.

You also have problems with your event handler registration - you're not waiting for the AJAX call to finish (and then add the table row) before registering the event handler.

This can be resolved by registering the event handler within the AJAX `success` callback, but given the first problem with your ID, a better solution would be to use a class (`.rmv`) instead of an ID and then use:

```
$('#recipes').on('click', '.rmv', function() {
   var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   // do something with the current row
});
```

The above code can be registered outside of the `success` callback because it uses *event delegation*.  It relies on the `click` event bubbling up to the enclosing table (which already exists), instead of directly registering the event on each button as they're created.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery function requires a '#' symbol to be appended if you are using id of an element to trigger any call. So Change

```
$('rmv').on('click', function() {
        alert('hello there!');
    });
```

to

```
$('#rmv').on('click', function() {
        alert('hello there!');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('/api/v1/recipe/?format=json', function(data) {
            $.each(data.objects, function(i, recipe) {
                $('table#recipes').append('<tr><td>' + recipe.title + '</td><td>' + recipe.ingredients + '</td><td>' + recipe.method + '</td><td><button class="btn" type="button" id="rmv">remove</button></td></tr>');
            });
            $('rmv').on('click', function() {
                alert('hello there!');
            });
        });
```

Attach the event handler in the success function of your ajax request.

Edit - As per others, your selector `rmv` is wrong, should be `#rmv`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rmv', table).on('click', function(){
     alert('hello there!');
});
```